# Algorithm for fast combinations

Tags: python

Input:Given `items=[1,2,3]` and `values=[100,300,800]` OR it can be in `dictionary={1:100,2:300,3:800}`.
Find  all combinations items such that sum values is less than 500

Solution:
`[1]`
`[2]`
`[1,2]`
This has to be done for millions of inputs.
WHat is the best and fastest algorithm to implement this??

Comment: Hello! What have you tried on your own so far?

Comment: Combinations of all lengths is essentially a power set. That means you generate `2**n` elements. For millions of inputs, that means `2**(10**6)`. That is a number with `300,000` digits. No matter the algorithm, this is gonna take lots of time unless the max total is really small with regard to most of the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much more efficient method is to use breadth-first-search and *avoid* enqueueing any further if the current item value plus the current sum already reaches the limit, so that in a value list of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and a limit of `5`, if the current combination of values is `[1, 2]` and the current item value is `3`, then since we find that `1 + 2 + 3` is already no less than `5`, we will not enqueue `[1, 2, 3]` for further search. This drastically cuts down on the number of combinations we need to test:

```
from collections import deque
def sums_less_than(items, values, limit):
    seeds = [(index, 0, [], item_value) for index, item_value in enumerate(zip(items, values))]
    queue = deque(seeds)
    while queue:
        index, _sum, combination, (item, value) = queue.popleft()
        new_sum = _sum + value
        if new_sum < limit:
            new_combination = combination + [item]
            yield new_combination
            for i in range(index + 1, len(seeds)):
                queue.append((i, new_sum, new_combination, seeds[i][-1]))
```

so that:

```
items=[1,2,3]
values=[100,300,800]
print(list(sums_less_than(items, values, 500)))
```

will output:

```
[[1], [2], [1, 2]]
```

Comment: what will be the efficiency of this method?

Answer (score 2):

```
import copy

dictionary = {
    100: 1,
    200: 2,
    800: 3,
}

value = sorted([100, 200, 800])

threshold = 500

res = []

def dfs(l, s, cur):
    if s < threshold:
        if len(l) > 0:
            res.append(l)
    else:
        return
    for i in range(cur + 1, len(value)):
        tmp = copy.copy(l)
        tmp.append(dictionary.get(value[i]))
        dfs(tmp, s+value[i], i)

dfs([], 0, -1)
print res
```

Time complexity is O(K). K is number of correct result.

Comment: Thanks. But can it be improved using bitwise approach? Because right now, I have given a small input but my actual input has millions of data... So,I wanted a faster approach. Consider this,  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-combinations-k-bit-numbers-n-bits-set-1-n-k-sorted-order/

Comment: The problem require all result output. So at least O(K) time complexity is required, cause you must write it out to stdout.

Comment: Use bitmap or not could not optimize this algorithm in order of magnitudes of time complexity.

Comment: Okay thanks.I need one more change, I want the sum to be printed along with the combination. ex: [1,2]:400

Comment: How could I tweak the above?

Comment: import copy
dictionary = {100: 1,200: 2,800: 3,50 : 4,}
value = sorted(dictionary.keys())
threshold = 500

res = []
thres_val=[]
def dfs(l, s, cur):
    if s < threshold:
        if len(l) > 0:
            res.append(l)
            thres_val.append(s)
    else:
        return
    for i in range(cur + 1, len(value)):
        tmp = copy.copy(l)
        tmp.append(dictionary.get(value[i]))
        dfs(tmp, s+value[i], i)

dfs([], 0, -1)
print(res)
print(thres_val)

print("\tItem list-->Value")
j=0
for i in res:
    print("\t",i,"-->",thres_val[j])

Comment: Python has a recursion limit of 1000 so if you're dealing with millions numbers in a list you're likely to hit the limit at some point.

Comment: Also, using values as dictionary index means that there can't be any duplicate values, which may not be a valid assumption.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.combinations` on a zipped sequence of items and values after filtering out values that are greater than the limit first:

```
from itertools import combinations
items=[1,2,3]
values=[100,300,800]
def sums_less_than(items, values, limit):
    filtered = [(item, value) for item, value in zip(items, values) if value < limit]
    return [[item for item, _ in c] for n in range(1, len(filtered) + 1) for c in combinations(filtered, n) if sum(value for _, value in c) < limit]
print(sums_less_than(items, values, 500))
```

This outputs:

```
[[1], [2], [1, 2]]
```

Comment: But what about *millions* of inputs? Even after the filtering, suppose you have 1,000,000 numbers left. Then, for example, 1,000,000 choose 50 is *3.283924e+235*.

Comment: Please feel free to contribute with better solutions if you find one.

Answer (score 0):

With modificaton:

```
import copy

dictionary = {
    100: 1,
    200: 2,
    800: 3,
    50 : 4,
}

value = sorted(dictionary.keys())

threshold = 500

res = []
thres_val=[]


def dfs(l, s, cur):
    if s < threshold:
        if len(l) > 0:
            res.append(l)
            thres_val.append(s)
    else:
        return
    for i in range(cur + 1, len(value)):
        tmp = copy.copy(l)
        tmp.append(dictionary.get(value[i]))
        dfs(tmp, s+value[i], i)

dfs([], 0, -1)
print(res)
print(thres_val)

print("\tItem list-->Value")
j=0
for i in res:
    print("\t",i,"-->",thres_val[j])`
```